# Best approach to handle "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

Currently what I do is checking if element exist in page, but my code has a lot if conditions because of that. Jquery event listeners don't show errors when an element doesn't exist. How does jQuery handle that and what techniques can I use for better design?

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');
var another_el = document.getElementById('another_el');

if(another_el){
el.addEventListener('click', swapper, false);
}

if(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', swapper, false);
}
....
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How jquery handles that...?

jQuery's API is *set-based*, not element-based. The DOM's API is element-based. When you do `$("#foo").on("click", ...)` in jQuery, if there's no element with the `id` `"foo"`, `$()` returns an *empty set*, not `null`, and calling `on` on that set doesn't do anything, but doesn't cause an error either.

Since `getElementById` returns an *element* or `null`, you have to have the check you've shown to prevent trying to call methods on `null`, which causes an error.

If you want the benefits of a set-based API without using jQuery, you *could* write your own set of utility functions that use `querySelectorAll` to give yourself a thin set-based wrapper around the DOM API, if you like.

Here's a very simple starter example:

```js
// The object we use as the prototype of objects returned by `domSet`
var domSetMethods = {
    on: function(eventName, handler) {
            // Loop through the elements in this set, adding the handler
            this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
                element.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
            });
            // To support chaining, return `this`
            return this;
        }
};
// Get a "DOM set" for the given selector
function domSet(selector) {
  // Create the set, usign `domSetMethods` as its prototype
  var set = Object.create(domSetMethods);
  // Add the elements
  set.elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  // Return it
  return set;
}

domSet("#foo").on("click", function() {
  console.log("foo clicked");
});
// Notice that even though there's no id="bar" element, we don't get an error
domSet("#bar").on("click", function() {
  console.log("bar clicked");
});
```

```html
<div id="foo">foo element (there is no bar element)</div>
```

You could add methods to `domSetMethods` that do other things. To support the chaining style of API jQuery provides, you return `this` in most cases from those methods.

Comment: Beautiful @T.J.