# getElementById and skip if null

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

When it returns null it does not run the next getElementById. What is the best way to structure this? There will be 12 possible getElementById but a page may only have 2 - 4

```js
document.getElementById("routeTwoName").textContent = "Tim";
document.getElementById("routeThreeName").textContent = "David";
document.getElementById("routeFourName").textContent = "Ricky";
document.getElementById("routeTenName").textContent = "Ric";
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <h4><span id="routeTwoName">Name</span></h4>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <h4><span id="routeTenName">Name</span></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: the code is in the title :D

Comment: So what is your actual question. It is unclear.

Comment: Have no clue what you were trying to do with that mark up in the question, I removed it so it would at least show your text

Comment: Sorry first time using stackoverflow. The script.js file has the four getElementById's. When it runs it will load routeTwoName but not routeTenName because routeThreeName & routeFourName are null. What is the best way to select and run the correct elements?

Comment: @Donnie - FWIW, I replaced your code blocks with a runnable snippet. When you can, that makes it really easy for people to see the problem and show you how to address it. Here's how to do some next time if you want: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out so I get it right next time. Gotta start somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you have this sort of repeated logic, you encapsulate the logic in a function:

```
function setText(id, text) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
        element.textContent = text;
    }
    return element;
}
```

then you can do this:

```
setText("routeTwoName", "Tim");
setText("routeThreeName", "David");
setText("routeFourName", "Ricky");
setText("routeTenName", "Ric");
```

Here's an updated version of the snippet from the question:

```js
function setText(id, text) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
        element.textContent = text;
    }
    return element;
}
setText("routeTwoName", "Tim");
setText("routeThreeName", "David");
setText("routeFourName", "Ricky");
setText("routeTenName", "Ric");
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <h4><span id="routeTwoName">Name</span></h4>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <h4><span id="routeTenName">Name</span></h4>
</div>
```

Another option is to give yourself a bunch of *set-based* DOM manipulation functions (like jQuery's API, but without using jQuery [unless you want to, of course; it's already written and tested]) rather than *element-based* ones like the DOM's. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602547/best-approach-to-handle-cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null-errors/50602594#50602594) has an example of starting down that path.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying an if statement but couldn't get the logic right. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So set a variable and see if it exists.

```
var x = document.getElementById("foo");
if (x) {
    x.textContent = "bar"
}
```